# exact word find - reddit bot

Tags: python, reddit

So I've been working on a reddit bot and have run into one issue. Lets say for example I trying to find all comments with the word "man" in it, the bot will find comments with this word but will also find comments with man in a word. For example "woman" . I only want it to find the exact word man.

I am using the package "praw" . I know this is going to be a really easy fix but for some reason I cant figure it out. This is the code to find the word in a comment.

```
if "man" in comment.body:
```

if you need to see more of the code just let me know. Any help would be great. Also I am using Python to make this bot.

Comment: Use regex instead? Python has support for it and it's generally easier to use than having to guess possible cases where that string shows up (e.g. line start/end, in the middle, etc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word `"man"` appears exactly in the word `"woman"`. You need to be more specific in your search, and that depends on the content of the comments. Perhaps you can search for `" man"` (but that would still count cases like `" manage"`), so perhaps you can do a regex search for whitespace followed by the string "man" followed by either whitespace or punctuation?